# bad_pool_caller stop: 0x000000c2

Tags: windows-xp, bsod

After installing Open Office and running it for the first time, my screen went all NES on me, I restarted my computer, and now every time I try to start windows (regular, any of the safe modes, last known good configuration) I get a BAD_POOL_CALLER blue screen with the stop code 0x000000c2

I had this error 2 months ago and was able to fix the problem by running some commands (fixmbr, fixboot, chkdsk) in the recovery console

Now, however (lucky me), when I select my windows install C:\Windows in the Recovery Console it gives me the BAD_POOL_CALLER error (same one as when I boot up)

I have dell sending me a new drive which I will pop in, reinstall windows, and start all over again (don't worry my data is backed up)

It would, however, be great to be able to boot the current drive up one more time to do some housekeeping like a list of programs I need to reinstall, a screen shot of my desktop, a backup of my firefox bookmarks

Does anyone have any tricks or tips for getting this puppy up and running?

Thanks!

PS Windows XP Service Pack 2

Comment: Should probably go over to http://superuser.com

Comment: @squillman - Apologies, coming from Stack Overflow, I thought that this was the place for these types of questions ... Super User is asking for a Beta Access password, which I obviously don't have, any suggestions?

Comment: Try ewok.adventure - I'll migrate this for you, so you don't have to recreate the question.

Comment: @kara-marfia ... thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some repeated advice from several forums:

- The hardware and RAM should be checked initially.
- Boot the system once again using the Operating System setup CD, or
  use a boot setup that has a GUI like BartPE.
- With RunScanner it is possible to use a memory test tool.
- Select a single account
- If all the accounts open then the system registry hive might be the
  problem.
- Locate the hive damaged and rename it, do not delete it.
- Create another hive from the backup or from the restore point.
- Initially uses the latest one and keep checking the restore points
  that come later.
- Avoiding harvesting any replacement hives from the hard drive
  booted Windows.
- After which compare the hives for differences.

I'd try booting from the install disk and running a repair.

Comment: unfortunately, running the Recovery Console from the Windows XP CD gives me the same error as trying to start up, so I can't run any repairs

Comment: Have you tried pulling some of your memory sticks out?  Depending on the type you may be able to take out half of them and try booting up.  The openoffice install may have been a coincidence.

Comment: Just boot from the disk, choose install and the choose repair.